# How can I write a server side java code to return any kind of file as stream using JAX-RS(Jersey)?

Tags: java, rest, file-io, jersey, jax-rs

I want a **java** code which should return any kind of file as stream using **JAX-RS (Jersey).** to the client side.

I have the following code,

```
@GET
@Path("/{name}")
@Produces("*/*")
public Response getFile(String name) {
    File file = new File("/path/of/the/file");
        FileInputStream fiS = new FileInputStream(file);
        StreamingOutput st = new StreamingOutput() {
            @Override
            public void write(OutputStream os) throws IOException {
                try {
                    int n;
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    while ((n = fis.read(buffer)) >= 0) {
                    os.write(buffer, 0, n);   
                   }
                   os.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new WebApplicationException(e);
                }
            }
        };
        ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok(st);
        response.header("Content-Type", "*/*");
    response.header("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + fileName);
        return response.build();
}
```

But it works only for `.txt, .html, .properties and .rtf`. Since I can download and get the actual content of the files in the client side for these file types.

But not sworking for the files with extension `.doc, .pdf, .png, .PNG, .jpeg, .mp3, .mp4` ..etc.

But I want a common code which should return any kind of files.

Output getting while returning the image. Image.PNG Tried with `content-type "image/png"`
[image]

Can anyone help me to fix this?

Comment: It seems it does not handle binary streams. Did you try by changing the headers/mime type? For example, "application/vnd.ms-excel.12" (.xlsx) instead of "*/*"

Comment: It can any kind of file. So how can I specify headers/mime type for all the types?

Comment: The browser have to know how to handle the HTTP response stream. I'm going to suggest an answwer.

Comment: Yes. Thanks for your prompt response. But I added content type as "image/png" for a file named ex: Image.PNG. Still I got a response like a unicode value. Please refer the attached screenshot

Comment: it looks ok. what is supposed to do the client with it? write to a file?

Comment: have you tried response.header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);

Answer (score 0):

You 'll have to render parametric the line `response.header("Content-Type", mimeType)`, setting per-response a suitable content-type. You could handle it as a map "*extension-file*" -> "*mime-type*", something like the following:

```
    //init in a run-once method (static, singleton, etc)
    final Hashtable<String, String> allowedTypes = new Hashtable<String, String>();
    allowedTypes .put("xls", "x-msexcel");
    allowedTypes .put("xlsx", "application/vnd.ms-excel.12");
    allowedTypes .put("mp3", "audio/mpeg3");
    allowedTypes .put("doc", "application/msword");
    //and so on, in a sort of white-list of allowed types

    //use the map
    final String default = "text/plain";
    String extension = getExtension(file); //not of interest here
    String curType = allowedTypes.get(extension)!= null ? allowedTypes.get(extension) : default;

    response.header("Content-Type", curType);
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer provided by robermann, the way to know the Mime-Type of the binary to send to client can be detected using [Apache Ticka](http://tika.apache.org/)

```
byte[] bs = ....
final String contentType = new Tika()
         .detect(new BufferedInputStream(new ByteteArrayInputStream(bs)));
MimeTypes allTypes = MimeTypes.getDefaultMimeTypes();
MimeType mimeType = allTypes.forName(contentType);
```

Now you can access object MimeType and sent its type into the header.

Ex: To know the file extension of the byte[], just add to code above:

```
mimeType.getExtension()
```

This will return : .pdf, .xml, .txt ...

Hope this helps!